# Have/get your book published

Tags: causative-have

Can I use both "have" and "get" in sentence #1? Would there be any difference in meaning between them in sentences #1 and #2?

> 1. **Get** / **Have** your book published on that site.
> 2. I **had** / **got**  my watch repaired.

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155631/does-get-have-a-more-active-or-urgent-meaning-than-have?rq=1)

Comment: I got my book published on that site. I had my book published on that site. Now, they are the same.

Comment: @Lambie, is there any difference in meaning?